# Is it possible to bind a parameter to a (unary) Proc object?

Tags: ruby

(Crossposting note: I have asked this already at the [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6879161) one week ago, but did not get any response yet).

**Here is a (very) simplified, working version of what I have so far:**

```
# A class S with two methods, one which requires one parameter, and
# one without parameters.
class S
  def initialize(s); @ms = s; end
  def s_method1(i); puts "s_method1 #{i} #{@ms}"; end
  def s_method2; puts "s_method2 #{@ms}"; end
end

# A class T which uses S, and "associates" itself to
# one of the both methods in S, depending on how it is
# initialized. 
class T
  def initialize(s, choice=nil)
    @s = S.new(s)
    # If choice is true, associate to the one-parameter-method, otherwise
    # to the parameterless method.
    @pobj = choice ? lambda { @s.s_method1(choice) } : @s.method(:s_method2)
  end

  # Here is how I use this association
  def invoke
    @pobj.call
  end
end
```

In this example, depending on how T is constructed, T#invoke calls
either S#s_method1 or S#S_method2, but in the case of calling
S#s_method1, the parameter to s_method1 is already fixed at creation
time of the T object. Hence, the following two lines,

```
T.new('no arguments').invoke
T.new('one argument', 12345).invoke
```

produce the output

```
s_method2 no arguments
s_method1 12345 one argument
```

which is exactly what I need.

**Now to my question:**

In the case, where `choice` is *nil*, i.e. where I want to invoke the
parameterless method `s_method2`, I can get my callable object in an
elegant way by

```
@s.method(:s_method2)
```

In the case where `choice` is non-*nil*, I had to construct a `Proc` object
using `lambda. This not only looks clumsy, but also makes me feel a bit
uncomfortable. We have a closure here, which is connected to the
environment inside the initialize method, and I'm not sure whether this
could cause trouble by causing memory leaks in some circumstances.

**Is there an easy way to simply bind a method object (in this case
`@s.method(:s_method1)` to a fixed argument?**

My first idea was to use

```
@s.method(:s_method1).curry[choice]
```

but this does not achieve my goal. It would not return a callable `Proc` object, but instead actually execute `s_method1` (this is not a bug, but documented behaviour).

**Any other ideas of how my goal could be achieved?**

Comment: Your lambda there, it __is__ a poor man's currying.

Comment: I know, and I was hoping that there is also some rich man's currying available ;-)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think it's the best you can get in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Saving parameters separately

This option is simple, but it might not be what you're looking for :

```
class T
  def initialize(s, choice=nil)
    s = S.new(s)
    @choice = choice
    @pobj = s.method(choice ? :s_method1 : :s_method2)
  end

  def invoke
    @pobj.call(*@choice)
  end
end

T.new('no arguments').invoke
T.new('one argument', 12345).invoke
#=> s_method2 no arguments
#=> s_method1 12345 one argument
```

## Method refinements for default parameters (Ruby 2.0+)

```
# Allows setting default parameters for methods, after they have been defined.
module BindParameters
  refine Method do
    def default_parameters=(params)
      @default_params = params
    end

    def default_parameters
      @default_params || []
    end

    alias_method :orig_call, :call

    def call(*params)
      merged_params = params + (default_parameters[params.size..-1] || [])
      orig_call(*merged_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's an example :

```
def f(string)
  puts "Hello #{string}"
end

def g(a, b)
  puts "#{a} #{b}"
end

using BindParameters

f_method = method(:f)
f_method.default_parameters = %w(World)

f_method.call('user') # => Hello user
f_method.call         # => Hello World

g_method = method(:g)
g_method.default_parameters = %w(Hello World)

g_method.call                    # => Hello World
g_method.call('Goodbye')         # => Goodbye World
g_method.call('Goodbye', 'User') # => Goodbye User
```

Your code can be rewritten :

```
class T
  using BindParameters
  def initialize(s, *choice)
    s = S.new(s)
    @pobj = s.method(choice.empty? ? :s_method2 : :s_method1)
    @pobj.default_parameters = choice
  end

  def invoke
    @pobj.call
  end
end

T.new('no arguments').invoke         # => s_method2 no arguments
T.new('one argument', 12_345).invoke # => s_method1 12345 one argument
```

## Monkey-Patching Method class (Ruby 1.9+)

If it is acceptable to patch the Method class, you could use :

```
class Method 
  def default_parameters=(params)
    @default_params = params
  end

  def default_parameters
    @default_params || []
  end

  alias_method :orig_call, :call

  def call(*params)
    merged_params = params + (default_parameters[params.size..-1] || [])
    orig_call(*merged_params)
  end
end
```

T becomes :

```
class T
  def initialize(s, *choice)
    s = S.new(s)
    @pobj = s.method(choice.empty? ? :s_method2 : :s_method1)
    @pobj.default_parameters = choice
  end

  def invoke
    @pobj.call
  end
end
```

## Wrapping Method class (Ruby 1.9+)

This way is probably cleaner if you don't want to pollute Method class :

```
class MethodWithDefaultParameters
  attr_accessor :default_parameters
  attr_reader   :method

  def initialize(receiver, method_symbol)
    @method = receiver.public_send(:method, method_symbol)
    @default_parameters = []
  end

  def call(*params)
    merged_params = params + (default_parameters[params.size..-1] || [])
    method.call(*merged_params)
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args)
    method.send(sym, *args)
  end
end
```

T becomes :

```
class T
  def initialize(s, *choice)
    s = S.new(s)
    @pobj = MethodWithDefaultParameters.new(s, choice.empty? ? :s_method2 : :s_method1)
    @pobj.default_parameters = choice
  end

  def invoke
    @pobj.call
  end
end
```

Any comment or suggestion are welcome!

Comment: I really like your approach with BindParameters (even though it wouldn't work for me right now, because I'm on Ruby 1.9.3, which doesn't have `refine` and `using` yet). While it is an overkill for the current problem, I think I could use this in other contexts as well.

Comment: Please feel free to mention any Ruby version requirements in your next question ;) I updated the answer with 2 scripts which should work with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like your `MethodWithDefaultParameters` best, because it has, IMO, the cleanest separation from other classes!